# How to show that the following process is a submartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ satisfying the usual conditions. Let $W$ be a Brownian Motion with respect to that filtration. We define the two processes

$X_t:=W^2_t$ and $Y_t:=\int_0^tX_sdX_s$

Then I want to prove:

1. $Y_t$ is a submartingale
2. $E[Y_t]=\frac{t^2}{2}$

This is exercise from an old exam. There are two hints: Using Itô to write $X$ in differential form and rewrite $Y$ accordingly. And if $U$ is standard normal distributed, then $E[U^6]=15$.

Using Itô I can write: $X_t=f(W_t)$ with $f(x)=x^2$. Hence Itô implies

$$dX_t=2W_tdW_t + dt $$

Therefore $Y_t=2\int_0^tW_s^3 dW_s + \int_0^tW_s^2ds$. Unfortunately I do not see how to proceed for both question. Some Help would be appreciated.

cheers

math

Comment: The hint about $\mathsf E[U^6]$ is scary

Comment: @Ilya me too! But it is really the hint, no typo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you know that the Ito integral is a martingale, so that $Y_t = M_t + \int_0^t W^2_s\mathrm ds$ and we only have to show that the latter integral is a submartingale. By definition we have
$$
  \mathsf E\left[\left.\int_0^t W^2_s\mathrm ds\right|\mathscr F_u\right] = \mathsf E\left[\left.\int_0^t W^2_s\mathrm ds\right|\mathscr F_u\right] = \int_0^u W^2_s\mathrm ds + \mathsf E\left[\left.\int_u^t W^2_s\mathrm ds\right|\mathscr F_u\right] \geq \int_0^u W^2_s\mathrm ds
$$
since $\mathsf E\left[\left.\int_u^t W^2_s\mathrm ds\right|\mathscr F_u\right]\geq 0$ as an integral of a non-negative function. Furthermore you have
$$
  \mathsf E[Y_t] = \mathsf E[M_t]+\mathsf E\left[\int_0^t W^2_s\mathrm ds\right] = 0+\int_0^t\mathsf E[W^2_s]\mathrm ds = \dots
$$

In order to address your point about the integrability, consider
$$
  \int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^n|\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P).
$$
We know that for even $n$ it is finite, so for odd $n$ we have
$$
  \int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^n|\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P) =
$$
$$
\int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^n|\cdot1(|W^n|\leq 1)\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P)+\int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^n|\cdot1(|W^n|>1)\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P)
$$
$$
  \leq t+\int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^{n+1}|\cdot1(|W^n|>1)\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P)
$$
$$
  \leq t+\int_{[0,t]\times\Omega } |W^{n+1}|\mathrm d(\lambda\otimes \mathsf P)<\infty.
$$

Comment: Is it in general true that $E[\int_0^t W^p ds]=\int_0^TE[W^p]ds$ for $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Here it is obvious, since for $p=2$ we have non negativity and can use Tonelli to interchange the two integrals. What if $p$ is odd? Can something be said for $E[\int_0^t f(W_s) ds]$ for a deterministic and say continuous function $f$? Which means can we then also always interchang the integrals: $E[\int_0^t f(W_s) ds]=\int_0^t E[f(W_s) ]ds$?

Comment: @math: I think you can just do Fubini which requires only integrability

Comment: For that we need product integrability. Why is this here that obvious?

Comment: @math: this indeed may not be obvious, let me check it

Comment: @math: added. You judge, how obvious it is :)

Comment: thanks for the update. However this trick does not apply in general case for a continuous $f$. I wonder if something can be said in this case, generally.

Comment: Not sure I understand: $E(|W_s|^n)=cs^{n/2}$ with $c=E(|W_1|^n)$, $s^{n/2}$ is bounded on the bounded interval $(0,t)$, end of the proof. For a general continuous function $f$, if $f$ is signed and $|f|$ increases wildly at infinity, there is no guarantee that the result holds.

Comment: @Did that's nice! thanks for this comment!

Comment: @Did: I am not sure whom did you refer to, but don't we have to have $\mathsf E\left[\int_0^t|W_s|^n\mathrm ds\right]<\infty$ as well - i.e. both double integrals of the absolute value has to be finite?

Comment: Anybody worrying about cases where $E(\int_0^t|W_s|^nds)$ is infinite and $\int_0^tE(|W_s|^n)ds$ is finite should check the statement of a certain theorem about integrals with respect to product measures named after an Italian mathematician.

Comment: @Did can something be said for a general continuous $f$?

Comment: @Did: please, don't hesitate to use "@" stuff - otherwise me or math may miss the comment

Comment: @math As I said, if $f$ is alternatively positive and negative and oscillates violently, the integrals might not even exist.

Comment: @Did Sorry, did not see your comment about the general case!

Comment: @math: consider $f(x) = x \mathrm e^{x^4}$. Then even if $\xi$ is just a standard random variable, the Lebesgue integral $\mathsf E[f(\xi)]$ does not exist since both the integral of the positive part and the one of the negative part are infinite. At the same time the function $f$ is not only continuous but also $C^\infty$. Recall that for diffusions in general you have conditions on the bounded growth of the drift and the diffusion term.

Comment: @Ilya and Did: Thanks for pointing out, what can go wrong in the general case!

Comment: @Did Sorry for bothering you, but just to be sure that I understand your comment $E[|W_s|^n]=cs^{n/2}$. The reason you mentioned that is the following: if $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $x\mapsto \int_Y|f(x,y)|d\nu (y)$ is $\mu$ integrable, then $f\in L^1(\mu\bigotimes \nu)$ and we can apply Fubini. In this case $X=[0,T]$ with lebesgue measure and $Y=\Omega$ with $P$. Am I right? Otherwise I don't get your comment.

Comment: Yes, and you simply reproduced the statement of F theorem.

Comment: @Did Thanks for you patience.